# None TypeErrorAttribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website however it returns an Error : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. can anyone assist me please. Thanks in advance.

```
  import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    def get_price(URL):
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        price = soup.find('span', {'itemprop': 'price'})['content']
        return price

    print(get_price('https://www.scan.co.uk/products/amd-ryzen-5-3600-am4-zen-2-6-core-12- 
   thread-36ghz-42ghz-turbo-32mb-l3-pcie-40-65w-oem'))
```

Comment: The correct url appears to be `https://www.scan.co.uk/products/amd-ryzen-5-3600-am4-zen-2-6-core-12-thread-36ghz-42ghz-turbo-32mb-l3-pcie-40-65w-oem`; website is protected by Cloudflare, and also blocking some VPN IPs. Maybe cloudscraper could be the way forward here.

Answer (score 2):

@platipus_on_fire_333 already has stated that the website is under cloudflare protection. Use cloudscraper instead of requests

**Example:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cloudscraper
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(delay=10,   browser={'custom': 'ScraperBot/1.0',})
url= url='https://www.scan.co.uk/products/amd-ryzen-5-3600-am4-zen-2-6-core-12-thread-36ghz-42ghz-turbo-32mb-l3-pcie-40-65w-oem'
r = scraper.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find('span', {'itemprop': 'price'})['content']
print(price)
```

**Output:**

```
154.99
```

[cloudscraper](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/)